# Some linear algebra question in infinite dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f : E \rightarrow F$ be a linear map, and $E$, $F$ two vector spaces. Assume that $F$ is finite dimensional, and call $r$ the rank of $f$. Is it true that 
$$r = \dim (E/\ker f)$$
?

Note that we typically don't assume $E$ to be finite dimensional.

Comment: Yes, $f$ induces an isomorphism $\overline{f}\colon E/\ker f \to \operatorname{im} f$, regardless of dimensions. So the two spaces have the same dimension.

Comment: right, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. This is a consequence of the [First Isomorphism Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_nullity_theorem#Reformulations_and_generalizations) applied to vector spaces. In particular, for *any* linear map $f:V\to W,$ $f$ induces an isomorphism $\overline f:V/\operatorname{ker}f\to\operatorname{im}f.$ Since the rank of $f$ is simply the dimension of its image, then the conclusion is immediate.

Comment: thank you for your answer !